# SUM based on specific item in IEnumerable vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a IEnumerable list of objects... Each object has many properties, one of which is called:

```
Amount
```

Amount is an integer value.

I need to get the sum of all the amounts.

I've been doing so by iterating over them:

```
For each item As MyObject In something
    amount += item.Amount
Next item
```

I'm mainly curious if there's a way I can strap a function on this to get the SUM, but only if this is a performance gain... Like a one liner, that's more efficient?

Comment: There is a more *concise* solution, but not a more efficient one.

Comment: @JerryFederspiel Thanks. Would you mind sharing? I suppose cleaner code helps with visual efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you requested it, a more concise solution is

```
Dim amount = something.Sum(Function(s) s.Amount)
```

But that is likely slower than the foreach loop.  If you have a List rather than just any old IEnumerable, then a for loop with an explicit index may be a tiny bit faster than your foreach:

```
For i = 0 to something.Count - 1
    amount += something(i).Amount
Next
```

Comment: Off by one bug fixed.

Comment: VB.NET-using-parens-instead-of-brackets-to-index syntax error fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the syntax in VB would be

```
amount = something.Sum(Function (item) item.Amount)
```

The `Sum` function is part of [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397910.aspx), and the `Function (item as MyObject) item.Amount)` syntax is a [Lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx). The `Sum` function takes a delegate which it will perform on each object to get a numeric value, and then it will sum those values and return them.

(You may need `Imports System.Linq` in your source file.)

Answer (score 0):

Because you used `IEnumerable(Of YourObject)`, then I prefer `foreach` or `LINQ` instead of `For` loop.

`IEnumerable` is Lazy collection which will be executed only and every time you call it.
So in the `For` loop it will be executed twice: `something.Count` and `something(i)`, when foreach and `LINQ` will be executed only once

Use `foreach`

```
Dim mySum As Int32
For Each item As YourItem in something
    mySum += item.Amount
Next
```

Or extension method `Sum`

```
Dim mySum As Int32 = something.Sum(Function(item) item.Amount)
```